# NVME boot drive will boot from bios not from startup

Tags: nvme

Windows 11.  Samsung 980PRO.  Windows installed in UEFI mode. When startup, will just hang and never error or boot.  Turn off, turn back on.  Bios says failed last time, hit F1 to run setup.  Select boot manager, click on 980PRO (listed first in boot sequence also), it will boot and run just fine.  If I reboot, I have to go through the same process, let it hang, turn off and back on, hit F1, boot from BIOS.  I have it set for no CMS, UEFI boot, secure boot.  It's like it's looking for the boot section but not finding it.  It's there and I have "repaired" it several times.  Have also tried another 980PRO
New computer, I9-12900, Asus TUF MB, 64GB ram
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Most Samsung SSD drives are very reliable. See if you can get Samsung Magician or other diagnostic app on bootable USB and test the drive.

Comment: I assume `Asus TUF` is a laptop?

Comment: Not laptop.  Desktop.  The drive seems fine. Passes Magician diagnostics.  I can't help but think it's a bios setting since it will boot and run just fine if I kick it off via bios.

Comment: Have you checked for updates to your BIOS?

Comment: Try to reinstall Windows on the NVMe drive while it's the only disk inside the computer. See also [this article](https://techtogamez.com/does-asus-tuf-z390-plus-support-nvme-boot/), although I can't validate its contents.

Comment: I get the impression the SSD is "slow to start" - i,e., needs more time then expected to get ready for access. One might wonder if it could be a content (boot setup) issue; run CHKDISK or similar on it?